# Probable Latex error - Ghostscript 9.25: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 2 points beyond the last page 1

Tags: miktex, eps, ghostscript

I ran the Latex->Latex->DviPS->PS2PDF and I get the following error:

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 2 points beyond the last page 1.

---

The .dvi and .ps are well generated. The output .pdf has only one page from 13. If I remove all my .eps pictures of the compilation I get no error and I get all the document without the pictures (obviously). I installed Miktex a few time ago because of new computer. The .tex file suffer no changes from the other computer.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,

Luis Gonçalves

```
\documentclass[journal,10pt,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[compress]{cite} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{epsf} 
\usepackage{psfrag}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}      
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[dvips,linktocpage,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref} \hypersetup{ colorlinks = true, linkbordercolor = {white}, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, allcolors=blue, }

\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\small} \usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{balance}

\def\degr{\hbox{$^\circ$}} \makeatletter \newcommand\figcaption{\def@captype{figure}\caption} \makeatother

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{6pt} \setlength{\intextsep}{6pt}

\newcommand{\comm}[1]{}

\begin{document} 
\begin{psfrags} 
\psfrag{Deteco}[Bc][Bc][0.8]{Detector} 
\psfrag{Utilizador}[Bc][Bc][0.8]{with} 
\psfrag{ZZ}[Bc][Bc][0.8]{FSC} 
\psfrag{Detteco}[Bc][Bc][0.8]{PIC} 
\psfrag{EE}[Bc][Bc][0.8]{Detector} 
\psfrag{YY}[Bl][Bl][0.8][0]{$U$} 
\psfrag{CC}[Bc][Bc][.8][0]{$r(t)$} 
\psfrag{BB}[Bc][Bc][0.65][0]{$H$} 
\psfrag{DD}[Bc][Bc][0.65][0]{$J$} 
\psfrag{FF}[Bc][Bc][0.65][0]{$I$} 
\begin{figure}[t] 
\centering \includegraphics[scale=22,angle=0]{fscpic.eps} 
\caption{} \label{pic} 
\end{figure} 
\end{psfrags}

\end{document}
```

%http://www.luisgo.pro/down/fscpic.eps

---

D:\zipback\paper\second_ieeta>ps2pdf exp.ps

Error: /invalidfont in /findfont

Operand stack:

AvantGarde-Gothic-latin1   AvantGarde-Gothic

Execution stack:

%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1967   2   6   %oparray_pop

Dictionary stack:

--dict:969/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:152/200(L)--   --dict:5/6(ro)(L)--   --dict:180/300(L)--   --dict:92/200(L)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: No such file or directory

Current file position is 149908

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: We will need to see the code. Make a small complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I would start by removing the images and then restoring them one at a time to find out which is causing the problem.

Comment: Nothing changed in the files since change of computer

Comment: Do you get the error if you use \usepackage[draft]{graphicx}?

Comment: With draft no error but also no picture

Comment: You can format your code as code. Mark it with the mouse, then look for the "{ }" button in the toolbar.

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me. Does it really errors for you?

Comment: Miktex installs the packages on the fly. Some missing package?

Comment: I changed the post. I think that my post has the clue for the solution

Comment: How to install NewCenturySchlbk-Roman-latin1   NewCenturySchlbk-Roman fonts in Miktex?

Comment: Solved. Missing fonts. I not understand why Miktex do not install on the fly.