# ps2pdf produces MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 \includegraphics

Tags: fonts, includegraphics, ghostscript

Cannot include any image in my LaTeX document.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,natwidth=1728,natheight=1152]{figures/tiger.jpg}
  \caption{Damn}
  \label{fig:your-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My compile sequence:

```
latexmk main.tex
dvips main.dvi
ps2pdf main.ps
```

My entire output:

```
C:\Users\Finn\tests\latex_tests\LaTeXchemscheme>latexmk main.tex
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP437, CP65001, CP1252)
I changed them all to CP1252
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 6 Nov. 2023. Version 4.81.
No specific requests made, so using default for latexmk.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
Rule 'latex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'latex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex  -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.12) (preloaded format=latex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cf
g)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def))
) (C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvip
s.def) (main.aux) <figures/tiger.jpg> [1] (main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 412 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.dvi'
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
Rule 'latex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main.aux

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex  -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.12) (preloaded format=latex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cf
g)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def))
) (C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvip
s.def) (main.aux) <figures/tiger.jpg> [1] (main.aux) )
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 412 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.dvi'
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date

Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)

C:\Users\Finn\tests\latex_tests\LaTeXchemscheme>dvips main.dvi
This is dvips(k) 2023.1 (MiKTeX23.12)  Copyright 2023 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2023.12.31:1556' -> main.ps
<C:/Users/Finn/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/tex.pro>
<C:/Users/Finn/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
<C:/Users/Finn/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/texps.pro>
<C:/Users/Finn/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/special.pro>.
<C:/Users/Finn/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
[1<./figures/tiger.jpg>]

C:\Users\Finn\tests\latex_tests\LaTeXchemscheme>ps2pdf main.ps
Error: /undefined in ????
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:969/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:105/200(L)--   --dict:103/300(L)--   --dict:43/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 42629
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

My log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.12) (preloaded format=latex 2023.12.31)  31 DEC 2023 15:56
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./main.tex
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cf
g
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2022/09/22 v3.1e Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
) (C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks18
\inpenc@posthook=\toks19
)
(C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvip
s.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2023-11-09 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count195
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box52
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count198
) (main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
File: figures/tiger.jpg Graphic file (type eps)
 <figures/tiger.jpg> [1

] (main.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 892 strings out of 474496
 16241 string characters out of 5744432
 1925457 words of memory out of 5000000
 23228 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,5n,65p,210b,210s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 412 bytes).
```

It is the same error as in this post:
[Probable Latex error - Ghostscript 9.25: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 2 points beyond the last page 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534133/probable-latex-error-ghostscript-9-25-error-a-pdfmark-destination-page-2-poi)
but their solution was to install missing fonts.

1. The image is a google image of a tiger without any text.
2. how do I know which fonts I am missing. Of the 2 fonts mentioned one is properly installed and the other (the one ending in -latin1) does not exist on google (at least not under that name).

Fonts mentioned in the other post but not clarified if these were the fonts missing or if it was others: "NewCenturySchlbk-Roman-latin1 NewCenturySchlbk-Roman"

Comment: you can't include jpg on the dvips-ps2pdf route. Why don't you use pdflatex?

Comment: My log file says that it is pdfLatex ("This is pdfTeX") or does that mean something else? How would I do that? Also I do need dvips-ps2pdf for other things happening in the main document. I just posted the part that produces the error.

Comment: your log says "preloaded format=latex" and not "preloaded format=pdflatex".  Run `latexmk -pdf` for pdflatex. And if you need the dvips route convert your pictures into eps.

Comment: Converting the images into eps first fixes everything. Thanks!